# Map generics in Java

Tags: java, generics

I seem to have a bit of misunderstanding with Java Generics and I hope you can help me. I tried to create a map like so:

```
Map<Debater, int>
```

(Debater is an Interface I declared) but java complained about the int, so I did:

```
Map<Debater, Integer>
```

I suppose it's because int is not a class while Integer is, is this correct?

Also, Now I get a Debater and I need to add 1 to its value in the map. How do I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

As for incrementing:

```
map.put(debater, map.get(debater) + 1);
```

[Autoboxing](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) will take care of "switching" between the object and the primitive.

Note that this (as noted in the comments) will throw a `NullPointerException` if you don't have a value for this debater in the map already. So if you want to do 2-in-1, it can be reworked as follows:

```
map.put(debater, map.containsKey(debater) ? map.get(debater) + 1 : 1);
```

Comment: This will throw a NullPointerException when the map does not contain the debater.

Answer (score 4):

That's correct. A [`Map`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) can only hold [`Object`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)s.

> Also, Now I get a Debater and I need to add 1 to <strike>it's</strike> its value in the map. How do I do that?

I suggest you to grab [`AtomicInteger`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) for that so that it's more failsafe in case of multithreaded environments.

```
Map<Debater, AtomicInteger> map = new HashMap<Debater, AtomicInteger>();
// ...

map.get(debater).incrementAndGet();
```

Else you'll need to add more code to `synchronize` the update to avoid that threads get the "wrong" value.

Answer (score 3):

> I suppose it's because int is not a
>   class while Integer is, is this
>   correct?

Correct.

> Also, Now I get a Debater and I need to add 1 to it's value in the map. How do I do that?

This should do the trick:

```
map.put(debater, map.get(debater)+1);
```

Comment: Neither int nor Integer are classes, they are both types. And both have classes representations: int.class and Integer.class. The difference is: int is a primitive type.

Comment: @Willi: java.lang.Integer is most certainly a class.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, it's because you have to specify a class.

As for your question, you juste have to do :

```
myMap.put(myDebater, myMap.get(myDebater) + 1);
```

All conversions between int and Integer will be done by [autoboxing](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html).

Answer (score 2):

You are correct about the int vs. Integer part.

To increment the value safely use:

```
Integer currentValue = map.get(debater);
if(currentvalue == null) {
    map.put(debater, 1);
} else {
    map.put(debater, currentValue  + 1);
}
```

or you could use `map.contains(debater)` first if you want to handle the case that a debater is not contained in the map separately.

Answer (score 2):

Java does not allow primitive types in generics. Fortunately, each of the primitive types has a "box" reference type, e.g. `Integer` for `int`, `Boolean` for `boolean`, etc. The language is aware of this association, and can do automatic boxing and unboxing for you. This means that you can do something like this:

```
 Integer i = 5;
 i++;
```

There are some caveats with automatic boxing/unboxing that you have to be aware of. The classic example is the following:

```
 List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 list.add(3);              // this is autoboxed, and calls list.add(E)
 list.remove(3);           // this invokes list.remove(int) overload !!!!
 list.remove((Integer) 3)  // this is how you call list.remove(E)
```

You will find that the above code as is will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, because the first `remove` tries to remove the 3rd element, instead of the element 3.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use primitive type (such as `int`, `float`, `char` etc.) as a generic type - collections in Java are generic. That's why you have to use `Integer` instead of `int`.